# Exception thrown due missing class though jar is in classpath, REST - JERSEY

Tags: java, rest, jersey, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using Jersey for REST apps, i'm getting this NoClassDefException for the class AbstractRuntimeDelegate
though i have the following Jars in my classpath....

- commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
- List item
- javax.ws.rs.jar
- jersey-core-1.9.1-sources.jar
- jersey-server-1.1.2-ea.jar

That class is in the jersey-core-1.9.1-sources.jar as i can see from here 
http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9.1/jersey-core-1.9.1-sources.jar?folder=com/sun/jersey/core/spi/factory/

Have you ever had this kind of issue?
Any advice?

Thank you

Piece of exception:

```
Exception in thread "bq-main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/spi/factory/AbstractRuntimeDelegate
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [jersey-core-1.9.1.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9.1/jersey-core-1.9.1.jar) instead of its source jar.